# line break in Jquery Mobile button does not fit to button height

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm adding 2 buttons in `Jquery Mobile` with text, each button takes half of the screen (horizontal).

```
<div>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" style="float:right;width:40%;">text a</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" style="float:left;width:40%;">text b,text b</a> 
</div>
```

When text in button is long text, I get a button with part of the text like that :

> "text b,te..."

How can I force the button to change the button height or break line so the text will fit the weight button and all the text will seen.

Comment: Could you provide link or jsfiddle?

Comment: well it's exactly those lines of code, text that doesn't fits to button width is cut.

Comment: Which version of jQM, 1.3.x or 1.4.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQM 1.4 you can just apply white-space: normal in CSS to the anchor element:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" >text a</a></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" >text b,text b</a>   </div>
</div>  

a {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

> jQM 1.4 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h3J8j/5/)**

For jQM 1.3, the CSS is aplied to the .ui-btn-inner span of the anchor:

```
a .ui-btn-inner {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

> jQM 1.3 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h3J8j/6/)**